# why hibernate changed HibernateException to (unchecked) RuntimeException

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I know that in some version Hibernate exceptions were changed to be unchecked. what is the reason? is this a philosophy issue or practical one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Practical. So you don't have to wrap every one of your operations regarding Hibernate in try catch blocks.

Taken from Java Persistence with Hibernate:

> A history of exceptions — Exceptions
>   and how they should be handled always
>   end in heated debates between Java
>   developers. It isn’t surprising that
>   Hibernate has some noteworthy history
>   as well. Until Hibernate 3.x, all
>   exceptions thrown by Hibernate were
>   checked exceptions, so every Hibernate
>   API forced the developer to catch and
>   handle exceptions. This strategy was
>   influenced by JDBC , which also throws
>   only checked exceptions. However, it
>   soon became clear that this doesn’t
>   make sense, because all exceptions
>   thrown by Hibernate are fatal. In many
>   cases, the best a developer can do in
>   this situation is to clean up, display
>   an error message, and exit the
>   application. Therefore, starting with
>   Hibernate 3.x, all exceptions thrown
>   by Hibernate are subtypes of the
>   unchecked Runtime Exception, which is
>   usually handled in a single location
>   in an application. This also makes any
>   Hibernate template or wrapper API
>   obsolete.

Comment: @T.J. yep, it would be good have it right here. I know I read this somewhere, so if I found that source, I'll post it here.

Comment: One of the many stupid decisions from Hibernate's staff. RuntimeExceptions are invisible if thrown inside a Thread: it only kills the Thread without any trace. RuntimeExceptions are forbidden in a library, this is very bad design.

Comment: Agreed. I now have to change all my classical try catches in the DAO layer and god knows where to RuntimeException. Imbeciles.